# How to change single item in RecyclerView without changing other layouts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to toggle the background color of a single item in a RecyclerView on click. I do this in the onClick function of a ViewHolder that implements OnClickListener. Here is the onClick implementation:

```
int position = getLayoutPosition();
if (selected.containsKey(position)) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    selected.remove(position);
} else {
    view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.highlight));
    selected.put(position, view);
}
```

The issue arises when I test this in a populated RecyclerView. If there are many items, selecting one at the start also highlights other items further in the list that are out of view. The other highlighted views are not added to the map 'selected'. Also, after scrolling away from selected views and returning to them, they sometimes change colors. Why does this happen, and how can I fix this?

Comment: I think your position is final https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837296/firebase-recycleradapter-displaying-wrong-information-android/53837770#53837770

Comment: You have to add new params in your POJO in RecyclerView. Let say "selected= true", then update it every time triggered, and your setnotifyOnChanged kan handle this changing

Answer (score 0):

That is a side effect of the views being recycled. They are literally being reused. Just make sure when your views are being bound you explicitly set the background color to the default color. That should do it.